# Creating deb and rpm from the same source

Tags: debian, fedora, python, packaging

Is there a standard for source packages to be able to build rpms, debs (and perhaps others) without too much customization?

I'm talking mostly about Python, PyQt programs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) can build debs/rpms from python packages on PyPI or from a local setup.py file. You can build a deb with

> fpm -s python -t deb $package-name-on-pypi

or

> fpm -s python -t deb setup.py

Building packages in other formats only requires you to change the `-t` (target type) parameter.

To produce debs I can also recommend [python-stdeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are looking for something like PyInstaller.

It can package the application for you in a very simple way.

Please have a look at the site.

http://www.pyinstaller.org/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyinstaller/

The downside is it can only handle up to Python 2.7

**Autopackage :**
If you want to package for different linux distributions you can try autopackage http://code.google.com/p/autopackage/

I do not have any experience with that so i do not know the details, and it seems to be unmaintained. I have looked through the code and it can be updated easily.

**Brief explanation :**
If you want to package for different distributions then there is no real tool that can do that flawless for you. Even PyInstaller has its issues. If you really want to support different distro's, the best way to go is to make packages for the distro you want and maintain/update these as your program grows.

Comment: Does it create rpms and debs or a 3rd party independent format?

Comment: It creates executables for Linux, Windows and OSX. it does not create .DEB and .RPM packages. For that you can try Autopackage. But I do not have any experience with that tool and the last release is quite old.

Comment: @Manuel Gutierrez : Thank you. I did not know about PyPi and stdeb, because I mostly develop in C++, and Ruby. +1 for your answer!